# Error on getting value of input text with jQuery and comparing it to another field

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get the val of a input text that is inside a dialog and compare it to a other field to check if there was any alterations/modifications..

let say that i have this:

```
var var1=_arrObjType1[0].Field1;
var var2= $("#EditText").val();
```

if after this i do an alert with both fields, they are empty..

```
alert(var1+ "---" +var2);
```

but when i try to print to the console by doing this:

```
console.log(var1.length);
console.log(var2.length);
console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
```

in the console appears this

> 1
>   0
>   ""

(an empty string)

both fields are empty and i am trying to compare to see if are equal or not...

Comment: var1 is not empty if it has a length of 1

Comment: it is empty,var 1 is obteined by getting a cell value on the table.the cell value is empty, but when i tried to get the value, it comes with a space in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use javascript's `.trim()`,

```
var var1=_arrObjType1[0].Field1;
var var2= $("#EditText").val();

if(var2.trim() === var1.trim()) {
  // both are equal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to cut off the leading and the trailing spaces and then compare them,

```
if($.trim(var1) === $.trim(var2)){
 //both are equal
}
```